# Mysql; Trigger Consultar total de registros por habitacion

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, trigger

Buenas Noches necesito ayuda ya que necesito realizar un trigger el cual me valide la cantidad de registros por habitacion de la tabla paciente y actualize el estado del campo estado en la tabla Habitacion a ocupado en caso de que la cantidad de personas registradas en esa habitacion sea de 3 o X personas.

```
CREATE TABLE Paciente
(
ID_Paciente BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Nombre_Paciente VARCHAR(25)NOT NULL,
Apellido_Paciente VARCHAR(25)NOT NULL,
Fecha_Nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
Descripcion_Enfermedad VARCHAR(150)NOT NULL,
Numero_Habitacion VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
Estado  varchar(15)
);

create table Habitacion
(
Numero_Habitacion VARCHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY ,
Piso bigint NOT NULL,
Tipo_Habitacion CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
Estado VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluí que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- para este trigger necesitas declarar un **contador** el cual te va ayudar a contar (valga la redundancia) los registros que tengan el mismo número de habitación
- con base en eso poner un **IF** cuya condición sea que sí el contador es mayor a 2, osea 3 personas registradas en la misma habitación registrará en la tabla ***Habitacion*** El estado "Ocupado" y los demas datos que contiene dicha tabla.

El TRIGGER quedaría mas o menos de la siguiente manera.

```
DELIMITER | 
CREATE TRIGGER habitaciones
AFTER INSERT ON Paciente
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @contador = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Paciente WHERE Numero_Habitacion = NEW.Numero_Habitacion);
    IF @contador > 2 THEN  
        INSERT INTO Habitacion
        SET Estado='Ocupado',
        Numero_Habitacion = NEW.Numero_Habitacion,
        Tipo_Habitacion= 'Nor',
        Piso=1;
    END IF; 
END;
|
DELIMITER;
```

EL TRIGGER EJECUTADO...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]